# Sitecore Turn Off SPEAK Dialog UI in 7.5

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5, sitecore-speak-ui

I have installed 7.5 and the progress was 7.0 -> 7.2 -> 7.5

However, when I click "Insert Link", "Media Link.. " and some specific link in content editor, Sitecore says the dialog path can not be found.

So, I knew that Sheer UI (old UI) replaced with SPEAK UI from 7.2. Many articles (https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/07/02/disable-sitecore-speak-dialogs/) says that I can comment out "overrideDialogs" node in "Sitecore.Speak.config" file to keep using old UI. But, the nodes are located at "Sitecore.Speak.Applications.config" file, not "Sitecore.Speak.config" file.

I tried to comment out the node in "Sitecore.Speak.Application.config" file, but it doesn't make the dialog UI pop up and it shows me the same error.

How can I change this back to use old dialog UI in 7.5?
Or, how can I enable SPEAK dialog UI in 7.5??

Answer (score 1):

How about taking a brand new 7.5 install and copying the "sitecore" directory to your existing, upgraded instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be achieved by disabling Speak overrideXmlControls in the Sitecore.Speak.config indeed. Create a custom configuration with the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <overrideXmlControls>
            <override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" with="/sitecore/client/applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaDialog">
            <patch:delete />
        </override>
    </overrideXmlControls>
</sitecore>
```

**Important!** Keep in mind **the order** so that the configuration file needs to be bellow the Sitecore.Speak.config in the Include folder otherwise the configuration file won’t work because the original Sitecore.Speak.config overrides won`t be registered (a good name will be z_Sitecore.Speak.Overrides.config). Full article available here:

http://sitecorecorner.com/2014/08/13/switch-sitecore-7-2-speak-ui-media-browser-to-the-good-old-sheer-ui-media-browser/